# Nextjs 14.0.3 Next auth 4.24.4 session callback missing the token on refresh, need to change tab and return to get the token

Tags: next.js, next-auth

The issue occurs when I built the app in production mode, it works fine in development mode.
But when running in production mode either locally and on Vercel the session token missing when I refresh the page. But when I change the browser tab or open another view and return, the page got re-rendered, and the session token got set.

```
 async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
            console.log("jwtCallback_Token", token);
            console.log("jwtCallback_User", user);
            console.log("jwtCallback_Account", account);

        

            if (account && account.provider !== "cognito_google") {


                token = { ...user }

            }

            else if (account?.provider === "cognito_google") {

                token = {
                    id_token: account.id_token,
                    access_token: account.access_token,
                    refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
                    cust_exp: user?.exp,
                    picture: user?.picture,
                    email_verified: user?.email_verified,
                    email: user?.email,
                    sub: user?.sub,
                    name: user?.name

                }
            }
            return token



        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            console.log("session-s", session);
            console.log("session-t", token);
            console.log("session-u", user);

            session.access_token = token.access_token

            return session


        },
```

i'm using client side components with
`const { data: session, status } = useSession()`

and retrieve the token with
`session?.access_token`

I want to retrieve the token immediately after refresh, without have to change tab first

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fix it, even though not with the best approach by using useEffect with update() from useSession hooks

Comment: Details solution is good to have

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you miss the arguments(NextAuthOptions) when using getServerSession?

Would you like to refer to this?
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession

```
// auth.ts

import type {
  GetServerSidePropsContext,
  NextApiRequest,
  NextApiResponse,
} from 'next';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from '@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/handler';

export function auth(
  ...args:
    | [GetServerSidePropsContext['req'], GetServerSidePropsContext['res']]
    | [NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse]
    | []
) {
  return getServerSession(...args, authOptions); // this!
}
```

```
// layout.tsx

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const session = await auth(); // use cases

  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```